# Querying Sphinx Search index using SphinxQL and PHP Script

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

I have a site, which allows users to search listings. I have all of the associated data stored in a database and I plan to use Sphinx to index and retrieve this info.

I want to use a PHP Script to retrieve this information, and my understanding is SphinxQL is the most up to date way of doing this (instead of using Sphinx API).

So how do I first implement Sphinx QL on Ubuntu 14.04? I have tried to read the documentation from Sphinx however have had no luck.

How do I then use PHP in a .php script to query the sphinx index and echo this?

I have tried to find a simplified example online however I can only find examples using the API.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=9306;charset=utf8', '', '');

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sample2 WHERE MATCH(:query)");

$sth->execute(array(':query' => '@title "bridge"'));

print_r($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Is pretty much a complete demo.

More featured demos: http://nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example.php

Comment: Hello Barry, 

thanks for your help it's helped me tremendously, however using the sample code (changing the $db variables) I had an error in my Apache logs regarding line 9: 

$PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':' in /$' in /var/www/html/test.php on line 9

Comment: Line 7 is: $sth->execute(array(':query' => '@title "bridge"'));

Answer (score 0):

Try the "sphinxQL" class from crVCL PHP Framework, http://en.cr-solutions.net/p/projects

This class is performance optimized and the library contain also a "sphinxQLBuilder" for the queries.